# Resize logical volume in ubuntu without damaging

Tags: server, partitioning, 20.04, virtualization, lvm

When I run `lsblk` i get as below

```
vda                       252:0    0   150G  0 disk 
├─vda1                    252:1    0     1M  0 part 
├─vda2                    252:2    0   1.5G  0 part /boot
└─vda3                    252:3    0 148.5G  0 part 
  └─ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv 253:0    0  74.3G  0 lvm  /
```

now i want to inrease size of `ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv` by writing

```
sudo lvextend -L +70G /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv
sudo resize2fs /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv
```

my `ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv` is in production.  My database and website is there. Resizing can damage it anyhow?

Comment: With sudo, you can damage anything anytime. That's why production systems should have a backup from which you can recover. Some admins have a minimal clone of the production to do testing as you want.

Comment: @Marco but in this scenario, can it delete or kill something? had u have experience with it?

Comment: I assume "+120G" will not work, because 74+120 > 150. In **most** cases `lvextend` and `resize2fs` will prevent you from killing the system. But it can always happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran those two commands safely without any problem:

```
sudo lvextend -L +70G /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv
sudo resize2fs /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv
```